# Stop Munin messages from /var/log/syslog

Tags: logging, syslog, munin

I am using munin on a system which is adding a log entry in syslog everytime the munin-node cron job executes. It is not an issue but it sometimes makes other errors spotting difficult. There are entries like

```
Feb 28 07:05:01 li235-57 CRON[2634]: (root) CMD (if [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all ]; then /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all update 7200 12 >/dev/null; elif [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt ]; then /etc/munin/plugins/apt update 7200 12 >/dev/null; fi)
```

every 5 minutes and I was wondering how can I stop the messages going into syslog. For munin specific errors I anyways have to keep an eye on /var/log/munin/*

Thanks
Sparsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on syslog. If use rsyslog(Ubuntu/Debian), you can edit /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:

```
#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
:msg,contains,"/etc/munin/plugins/apt_all update 7200" ~
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
```

It's a cron syslog message(not Munin).

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I added this exactly into my rsyslog.d/50-defauly.conf file. I restarted cron but still see the logs from munin in syslog. Do I need to do something else as well.

Comment: Yes. You need restart rsyslog: /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use **apt_all** munin plugin you can just comment out this cron job in

```
/etc/cron.d/munin-node
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a munin message, it's a cron message.  It's possible to stop all cron messages from going into /var/log/syslog, and/or to send them somewhere else, but that's all.  Would you like to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer above (I cannot edit or comment): for newer Munin versions the information provided by syslog is different:

```
CRON[9413]: (root) CMD (if [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all ]; then munin-run apt_all update 7200 12 >/dev/null; elif [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt ]; then munin-run apt update 7200 12 >/dev/null; fi)
CRON[9414]: (munin) CMD (if [ -x /usr/bin/munin-cron ]; then /usr/bin/munin-cron; fi)
```

In `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, underneath `# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.`, add following two lines:

```
:msg, contains, "then /usr/bin/munin-cron" ~
:msg, contains, "then munin-run apt_all update 7200 12" ~
```

Then restart the rsyslog process:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Using Munin 2.0.17-2ubuntu1 on Ubuntu Saucy.